# How to get elements of an array with overflow / PHP

Tags: php, arrays, overflow

I initialize an array with all month as elements:

```
$allmonths = array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", 
                    "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", 
                    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", 
                    "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
```

I also have a user interface, where you can select a timeinterval. This timeinterval should be the x-axis of a chart. In the following code "`$month[0]`" is the first month on the x-axis, "$month[1]" is the last one and "`$diffyear`" is the difference between the selected year.

```
$x_scale = array();
    $i = $month[0]-1;
    $length     = 12 * $diffyear - $month[0] + $month[1];
    while($length >= 0){
            $x_scale[] = $allmonths[$i];
            $i++;
            if($i == 12){
                $i=0;
            }
            echo "I : $i";
            $length--;
        }
```

If "`$i`" was 12 times incremented, the `$x_scale` array is filled with empty elements. I don't know, how i can solve this problem... Thanks to every answer

Comment: I don't get your mean? what are you want? Is this not right? https://eval.in/748014

Comment: Mhm... yep this is right! Now I looked up what my x_scale is and it is the same. But the x-axis of my chart ends with the 12th element in the x_scale array. All elements which are selected twice aren't show... I think it's a problem with the framework...

Answer (score 0):

It seems the values are assigned before the if condition.you have to write this code after the if condition =>

```
  $x_scale[] = $allmonths[$i];
```

Just check it out and reply me..

Comment: It was already right, seems like there is problem with the razorflow framework, which I'm using for the charts. But thank your very much!

Answer (score 0):

okay I solved it!

```
$x_scale = array();
$i = $month[0]-1;
$x_year = year[0]-2000   //Use the begin year, subtract 2000: 2016 => 16
$length     = 12 * $diffyear - $month[0] + $month[1];
while($length >= 0){
        $x_scale[] = $allmonths[$i]."'".$x_year; //adding years to months
        $i++;
        if($i == 12){
            $x_year++;                          //increment year
            $i=0;
        }
        echo "I : $i";
        $length--;
    }
```

Now the each elements of the array are different and will be shown in the chart!

excuse me for the troubles and thanks for your response!